# jQuery get this div text

Tags: jquery, html

I have a question. I have multiple classes like this:

```
<div class="test">
    <div class="this-text">
    Text 1
    </div>
</div>

<div class="test">
    <div class="this-text">
    Text 2
    </div>
</div>

<div class="test">
    <div class="this-text">
    Text 3
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the text so in every div I have

```
<script>
$(this).find(".this-text").text();
</script>
```

But the result is Text 1Text 2Text 3, how can I get the text from "this" div and not the other div's. I hope someone can help me and my explanation is understandable.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Henk, try this:

```
<script>
   $(this).find(".this-text").first().text();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the content of the Nth `.test` with `$(".test:eq(N-1) .this-text").text()`, so to get the second text, write `$(".test:eq(1) .this-text").text()`.

see fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/t9L8e/

Answer (score 0):

You could use a

`$("div.test").each()` for your .test div and then print the text for each one

Otherwise `.find(".this-text")` will retrieve you all the divs with that class.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eddiarnoldo/4e3eK/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".test").each(function () {
    alert($(this).find("div").html());
});
```

See this fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/Za76E/

Answer (score 0):

The following piece of code finds the children of your div with the matching class.

```
  <script>
   $(this).children(".this-text").text();
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use a

$(this).children(".this-text").text()

Comment: use :first for call the first class $(".test:first").each(function(){
    
    console.log($(this).children(".this-text").text())

})